# How to position input label at the top if input has a value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create an input. If we click on the input or write something. I want the label to go to the top. how can I keep the shrink class on my label. if the input have a value? can I do this without using javascript.

```css
.input-group {
  position: relative;
}

.input-group .form-input {
  display: block;
  background: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.input-group .form-input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #d80810;
}

.input-group .form-input:focus ~ .form-input-label {
  top: -18px;
  left: 5px;
  color: #181d2f;
}

.input-group .form-input-label {
  color: #8995a2;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 8px;
  top: 8px;
  -webkit-transition: 300ms ease all;
  transition: 300ms ease all;
}

.input-group .form-input-label.shrink {
  top: -18px;
  left: 5px;
  color: #181d2f;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" id="username" class="form-input" />
  <label for="username" class="form-input-label">Username</label>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the actual expectation here ? When we click on input box, I see that label is already moving to top of input box without using JavaScript.

Comment: @abhinav3414 If you type something and click somewhere else it comes down again.

Comment: Not perfect, but this should work, but needs a placeholder: input:not(:placeholder-shown) { border:1px solid red; }

Comment: You've added `JavaScript` tag to the question...
I'd say: use JavaScript...
If you don't want to use JavaScript - why did you tag the question with it?

Comment: Ideally these kind of behaviors should be handled with JavaScript. It would be very hard/complex/unconventional if you want to solve it without using JavaScript.

Comment: Alright, I'll do it with javascript. I just wanted to see if there's a way without javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it using `JavaScript` and `CSS` with `:not` pseudo class.

- Set inital value of `input` to `""` and set the `input` value when `keyup` using Javascript.
- On `CSS`, using `:not` pseudo class, you can implement the same style on label like focus.

```
.input-group .form-input:not([value=""]) ~ .form-input-label,
.input-group .form-input:focus ~ .form-input-label {
  top: -18px;
  left: 5px;
  color: #181d2f;
}
```

```css
.input-group {
  position: relative;
}

.input-group .form-input {
  display: block;
  background: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.input-group .form-input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #d80810;
}

.input-group .form-input:not([value=""]) ~ .form-input-label,
.input-group .form-input:focus ~ .form-input-label {
  top: -18px;
  left: 5px;
  color: #181d2f;
}

.input-group .form-input-label {
  color: #8995a2;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 8px;
  top: 8px;
  -webkit-transition: 300ms ease all;
  transition: 300ms ease all;
}

.input-group .form-input-label.shrink {
  top: -18px;
  left: 5px;
  color: #181d2f;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" id="username" class="form-input"  onkeyup="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" value="" />
  <label for="username" class="form-input-label">Username</label>
</div>
```