# How to add event listener to mulitple inputs with same class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have style input field with HTML and CSS. If we focus on the input I'm shrinking the label with CSS. but If we click somewhere else the label does not shrink. So I'm checking for the input value with javascript and shrinking the lable if the input have value. but the current code only applies on the first input.

How can I fix this?

```js
document.querySelector('.input-group .form-input').addEventListener('input', shrinkLabel);

function shrinkLabel(e) {
  const input = e.target,
    label = input.nextElementSibling;

  if (input.value.length > 0) {
    label.classList.add('shrink');
  } else {
    label.classList.remove('shrink');
  }
}
```

```css
.input-group {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.input-group .form-input {
  display: block;
  background: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #202124;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 13px 15px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}

.input-group .form-input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #d80810;
}

.input-group .form-input:focus ~ .form-input-label {
  font-size: 14px;
  top: -12px;
  color: #d80810;
}

.input-group .form-input-label {
  background: #fff;
  color: #80868b;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 0 7px;
  left: 8px;
  top: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: 300ms ease all;
  transition: 300ms ease all;
}

.input-group .form-input-label.shrink {
  font-size: 14px;
  top: -12px;
  color: #d80810;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group mb-4">
  <input
    type="text"
    name="username"
    value=""
    id="username"
    class="form-input"
  />
  <label for="username" class="form-input-label">Username</label>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <input
    type="password"
    name="password"
    value=""
    id="password"
    class="form-input"
  />
  <label for="password" class="form-input-label">Password</label>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use simple HTML and CSS to achieve this. Ref: https://codepen.io/kravisingh/pen/jYGeyY

Comment: @kravisingh I've already posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64523458/how-to-position-input-label-at-the-top-if-input-has-a-value) about how to do this without javascript. but didn't get the answer. so I've done it with javascript.can you please answer there. so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.input-group .form-input').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('input', shrinkLabel);
});
```

`.querySelectorAll` should work here!

Answer (score 4):

`document.querySelector` returns the first `Element` within the document that matches the specific selector.

So that `addEventListener` will be applied on the first `input` only.

To get all matched elements, it is needed to use `document.querySelectorAll`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.input-group .form-input').forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('input', shrinkLabel);
});

function shrinkLabel(e) {
  const input = e.target,
    label = input.nextElementSibling;

  if (input.value.length > 0) {
    label.classList.add('shrink');
  } else {
    label.classList.remove('shrink');
  }
}
```

```css
.input-group {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.input-group .form-input {
  display: block;
  background: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #202124;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 13px 15px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}

.input-group .form-input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #d80810;
}

.input-group .form-input:focus ~ .form-input-label {
  font-size: 14px;
  top: -12px;
  color: #d80810;
}

.input-group .form-input-label {
  background: #fff;
  color: #80868b;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 0 7px;
  left: 8px;
  top: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: 300ms ease all;
  transition: 300ms ease all;
}

.input-group .form-input-label.shrink {
  font-size: 14px;
  top: -12px;
  color: #d80810;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group mb-4">
  <input
    type="text"
    name="username"
    value=""
    id="username"
    class="form-input"
  />
  <label for="username" class="form-input-label">Username</label>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <input
    type="password"
    name="password"
    value=""
    id="password"
    class="form-input"
  />
  <label for="password" class="form-input-label">Password</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.querySelectorAll()`. You would then need to add your event listener with a `forEach` loop.

This example is from this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```
var highlightedItems = userList.querySelectorAll(".highlighted");

highlightedItems.forEach(function(userItem) {
  deleteUser(userItem);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because document.querySelector returns only the first result.
you should instead use document.querySelectorAll('.input-group .form-input')
that will return a list of available inputs
then, you should loop over that list and add the event listener to each of the inputs

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input-group .form-input')
if (inputs && inputs.length) {
  inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('input', shrinkLabel));
}

function shrinkLabel(e) {
  const input = e.target,
    label = input.nextElementSibling;

  if (input.value.length > 0) {
    label.classList.add('shrink');
  } else {
    label.classList.remove('shrink');
  }
}
```

```css
.input-group {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.input-group .form-input {
  display: block;
  background: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #202124;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 13px 15px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}

.input-group .form-input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #d80810;
}

.input-group .form-input:focus~.form-input-label {
  font-size: 14px;
  top: -12px;
  color: #d80810;
}

.input-group .form-input-label {
  background: #fff;
  color: #80868b;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 0 7px;
  left: 8px;
  top: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: 300ms ease all;
  transition: 300ms ease all;
}

.input-group .form-input-label.shrink {
  font-size: 5px;
  top: -12px;
  color: #d80810;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group mb-4">
  <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username" class="form-input" />
  <label for="username" class="form-input-label">Username</label>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" class="form-input" />
  <label for="password" class="form-input-label">Password</label>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" name="other" value="" id="other" class="form-input" />
  <label for="other" class="form-input-label">other</label>
</div>
```

Note: I've set the font size to a very small value to make sure the change is easily noticed

Answer (score 0):

if you a little bit modificate your inputs and put placeholder=" " then you can use pseudo class :placeholder-shown to catch not empty inputs and you can achieve you goal without js.
[JsBin](https://jsbin.com/kicuxilika/edit?html,css,output)

```css
.input-group {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.input-group .form-input {
  display: block;
  background: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #202124;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 13px 15px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}

.input-group .form-input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #d80810;
}

.input-group .form-input:focus ~ .form-input-label
{
  font-size: 14px;
  top: -12px;
  color: #d80810;
}

.input-group .form-input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .form-input-label {
  font-size: 14px;
  top: -12px;
}

.input-group .form-input-label {
  background: #fff;
  color: #80868b;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 0 7px;
  left: 8px;
  top: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: 300ms ease all;
  transition: 300ms ease all;
}

.input-group input:not(:empty) + label {
  font-size: 14px;
  top: -12px;
  color: #d80810;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group mb-4">
  <input
    type="text"
    name="username"
    placeholder=" "   
    value=""
    id="username"
    class="form-input"
  />
  <label for="username" class="form-input-label">Username</label>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <input
    type="password"
    name="password"
    placeholder=" "     
    value=""
    id="password"
    class="form-input"
  />
  <label for="password" class="form-input-label">Password</label>
</div>
```